# angular route not working on server apache2

Tags: angularjs, apache, angularjs-ng-route

I have an angular app that works perfectly in localhost. I uploaded to a server and the layout-blade works perfectly, but it can not find the index page that goes in the ng-view. It just returns a 404 error.

Here is the approutes.js

```
angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', '$httpProvider',function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/index',
    controller: 'MainController'
  })
```

The index is in /resources/views/partials

The layout blade is in /resources/views

The head of that html has

I am in an apache2 server in an ubuntu machine.

Any ideas?

edit:
This is my .htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If it works local with pretty url's it's because you configured local to always serve app entry point.

Comment: I am using a bolierplate so I did not configure anything. Any help on how to configure local or app entry point will really help

Comment: basically need mod rewrite which can put in htaccess. Should be easy to search

Comment: I just added my htaccess but I do not know how to rewrite it or even if I have to

Comment: That redirect makes it possible to load the index.php which loads the layoutblade, which is working. The problem is that it is not loading the rest of the partial views in the angular route service

Comment: Use browser dev tools network to check  template requests. You do have html5mode set in config right? Not shown in question config

Answer (score 1):

In your root directory make a file named .htaccess
and following code to that file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# not rewrite css, js and images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed by changing the AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All. That did that trick. Thanks